# How to set user name and password in a HTTP get request?

Tags: python, http, authentication, get-request

I have use `requests` library from Python to send a get request:

```
response = requests.get(url, verify, auth, params, headers)
```

My assumption was that one can send any get-request directly from a browser. For example, in the address line of a browser I need to put something like that:

```
http://my_url.net?param1=12&param2=777
```

In the above way I can set `url` and `params` that I use in my Python function. But how can I set `auth` (user name and password) in the get request in case if I use browser to send the request. The same question is applicable to the remaining two arguments: `verify` and `headers`.

Comment: You can try the format of `http://{username}:{password}@my_url.net?param1=12&param2=777` however you cannot just add headers using the browser address bar

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your browser, I guess you can find extensions that can help you do that.

If you use cUrl, you can do something like :

```
curl http://my_url.net?param1=12&param2=777 --header "Authorization: Basic XXX"
```

where "xxx" is the Base64 encoding of the string "username:password".

Comment: */5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -qO- http://my_url.net?param1=12&param2=777 --header "Authorization: Basic XXX" >> /home/boo/logs/cron.log

Answer (score 0):

Or try this, using a [password manager with a default realm](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm):

```
url = "http://my_url.net?param1=12&param2=777"

pw_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
pw_mgr.add_password(None, url, username, password)

urllib2.install_opener(
    urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(pw_mgr)))

request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: I would like to provide a link that a user can use in a browser.

Comment: Aha, sorry then I misunderstood your question. @PeeHaa's comment is the only way that I know of.